# Unable to build and run an app on Android Studio 2.2 preview

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using the Android Studio 2.2 preview, and now when I try to build my project, I get this message in gradle build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
value (69601) > 0x0000ffff
```

Couldn't find any of the same errors in other questions, What's causing this? possible fix?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to `File/Invalidate and Restart` and then Click `Invalidate Restart`. may be it solve your problem.